# Allowing Windows Server 2012 R2 access to directory on AIX 7.1

Tags: windows, aix, cifs

we have two AIX servers, Live and Test. On our live server, I am able to add an entry into smb.conf to allow a directory to be shared across a Windows network as shown in the extract below, displaying the ImportExport shared folder in Explorer:

```
[ImportExport]
        comment = Import Export directory
        path = /path/folder
        browseable = Yes
        hosts allow = <IP>
        guest ok = Yes
        force user = <user>
        forcegroup = pro4
        read only = No
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        dead time = 10
```

However, adding a very similar configuration on our Test server, I cannot even get to the server from a Windows box, I get the "\ is not accessible..." message as if the server does not exist, or there are no shares.

Is there anything else I need to do to the local AIX folder to get this visible to Windows, or can you give me some ideas of what the pre-reqs are for this?

Sorry, I am not an AIX specialist, primarily a Windows house.

Thanks

Comment: What does `smbclient -NL <server_ip>` say?

Comment: Without posting the screenshot, as it contains sensitive server names and descriptions, it lists all the shares created, including the one I created in smb.conf. Under Workgroup/Master, I get "Workgroup" and then the name of another AIX box, but it's the production box and not the name of the current test box. Should I expect to see a record to match the name of the server where the shares are hosted? The production box correctly shows a Workgroup/Master record with the production server name.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working now - Samba 3.2.0 was restricted to 14 chars or less for the share name. Reduced, restarted SAMBA and now OK. Thanks all